# How do I fix a keras error for a plaidbench keras test?

Tags: keras, plaid, plaidml

I am trying to install plaidml-keras so I can use non-Nvidia GPUs with Keras in python/jupyter. After clearing several other hurdles I get as far as:

```sh
plaidbench keras mobilenet
```

but it errors twice

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'object_list_uid' from 'keras.utils.generic_utils' (/Users/me/sprinthive/src/notebooks/nbenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py)

File "/Users/me/sprinthive/src/notebooks/nbenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plaidbench/frontend_keras.py", line 321, in __init__
raise core.ExtrasNeeded(['plaidml-keras'])
plaidbench.core.ExtrasNeeded: Missing needed packages for benchmark; to fix, pip install plaidml-keras
```

This is in spite of already having plaidml-keras installed:

```sh
pip freeze | grep plaid
plaidbench==0.6.4
plaidml==0.6.4
plaidml-keras==0.6.4
```

[I am using 0.6.4 to make it work on macOS 10.13 High Sierra]

How can I resolve the above errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Plaidbench was not tested for newer python versions. Its translated error message also masked the issue. I used python 3.10 and got the same error message. The line 321 of /site-packages/plaidbench/frontend_keras.py is

```
importlib.import_module('plaidml.keras').install_backend()
```

I ran it manually and it actually throws the following ImportError

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'collections' in Python
```

The Iterable class was removed from collections in Python 3.10 (details on this can be find at https://stackoverflow.com/a/72032097). PyPi and https://github.com/plaidml/plaidbench/blob/master/setup.cfg showed that plaidbench specified Python 3.5 and https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml/blob/plaidml-v1/environment.yml specified Python 3.7. With a fresh python 3.7 virtual environment and simply do

```
pip install plaidml-keras plaidbench
```

Or recreated with the following requirements just in case you want to pin down the versions

```
cffi==1.16.0
click==8.1.7
colorama==0.4.6
enum34==1.1.10
h5py==3.10.0
Keras==2.2.4
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
numpy==1.24.4
plaidbench==0.7.0
plaidml==0.7.0
plaidml-keras==0.7.0
pycparser==2.21
PyYAML==6.0.1
scipy==1.10.1
six==1.16.0
```

then the error is gone. This works with Python 3.8 too but you has to stay at 3.7 or below for tensorflow support in PyPI.

Just a side note: Anaconda makes it easier for canned solution but suffer from limited choices of packages. Potential issues could rise when one has to mix packages from different sources or just channels. PyPI has many more choices but more combinations to test, and sometimes still requires compilation from the source.

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out by creating a virtual environment with Anaconda. Beware that I am working on Windows, so this might not be a solution for your problem. If I had to guess, something was installed by me before that causes a python package problem. I think this is related to the tensorflow library, but I haven't dug into that. I would recommend trying out a fresh virtual environment on your Mac, where you install the plaidml package. The error Message before was exactly the same.