# ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'collections' in Python

Tags: python, python-module

Working in Python with Atom on a Mac.
Code:

```
from rubik.cube import Cube
from rubik_solver import utils
```

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Audey/Desktop/solver.py", line 2, in <module>
    from rubik_solver import utils
  File "/Users/Audey/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/rubik_solver/utils.py", line 4, in <module>
    from past.builtins import basestring
  File "/Users/Audey/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/past/builtins/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from past.builtins.noniterators import (filter, map, range, reduce, zip)
  File "/Users/Audey/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/past/builtins/noniterators.py", line 24, in <module>
    from past.types import basestring
  File "/Users/Audey/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/past/types/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .oldstr import oldstr
  File "/Users/Audey/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/past/types/oldstr.py", line 5, in <module>
    from collections import Iterable
ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'collections' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

The `from rubik_solver import utils` is what is causing the error as when I remove it the error does not appear. I am not sure what is causing the error and hove checked there code and found it on other sources so am sure that it *should* work.
Any solves?

Comment: When searching for this error, it seems that Python 3.10 has compatibility issues which cause this error to appear; I saw it suggested that you install and use Python 3.9 in the meantime. Does that fix it? I assume you'd already looked up the error and tried some stuff, but you didn't mention anything about doing that.

Comment: Yep will try. Did look it up but didn't find this :)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The `Iterable` abstract class was removed from `collections` in Python 3.10.  See the deprecation note in the 3.9 [`collections` docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html).  In the section [Removed](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#removed) of the 3.10 docs, the item

- Remove deprecated aliases to [Collections Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) from the `collections` module. (Contributed by Victor Stinner in bpo-37324.)

is what results in your error.

You can use `Iterable` from `collections.abc` instead, or use Python 3.9 if the problem is in a dependency that can't be updated.

Answer (score 43):

As said in other answers, the issue is the deprecation of some aliases from `collections.abc` into `collections` from python 3.10.

If you can't modify the importations in your scripts because of a third-party import, as a temporary workaround you can do the aliases manually before importing the problematic third-party lib. See the example below for the importation of `hyper` library for example, which causes similar issues as yours.

```
import collections.abc
#hyper needs the four following aliases to be done manually.
collections.Iterable = collections.abc.Iterable
collections.Mapping = collections.abc.Mapping
collections.MutableSet = collections.abc.MutableSet
collections.MutableMapping = collections.abc.MutableMapping
#Now import hyper
import hyper
```

Comment: This is the quickest solution but also the dirtiest. Other silent, non-breaking changes can occur using a dependancy with an unsupported version of python.

Comment: This quickly resolved my blocker in Python 3.11 for the the EDI library badx12:
`from badx12 import Parser`

Thank you!

Comment: had to add `collections.Iterator = collections.abc.Iterator` to fix glusterfs gfapi.

Answer (score 17):

In python version `3.10` you should import `Iterable` from `collections.abc` instead:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable
```

or you can:

```py
try:
    from collections.abc import Iterable
except ImportError:
    from collections import Iterable
```

Answer (score 4):

You will have two files namely *oldstr.py* and *misc.py*

In *misc.py*:
change `from collections import Mapping` to `from collections.abc import Mapping`

and

In *oldstr.py*:
change `from collections import Iterable` to `from collections.abc import Iterable`

Simply... just add `.abc` after `collections` on import statement

Comment: stack trace on error told me the django-related files making collections imports - added .abc and that did it

Comment: Here is the sed commands I had to apply to make very old Django to work with Python >= 3.10: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/website/blob/f6d69ec4a247a1df06b09c0e6e9989c88ea0d1c1/.github/workflows/tests.yml#L38-L46