# Getting Import Error: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'collections' in pycaret

Tags: python, collections, iterable, pycaret

I am using 3.10 version of python and while running pycaret.classification i am getting below error.

```
      1 #init setup
----> 3 from pycaret.classification import *
      4 s = setup(data, target ='Resolver',session_id=123)
      6 #train model


ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'collections'
```

Note: I tried using `collections.abc import Iterable` in my script, but it is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'collections' in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72032032/importerror-cannot-import-name-iterable-from-collections-in-python)

Comment: `pycaret` doesn't officiallly support Python 3.10 - use versions 3.7-3.9.

Answer (score 0):

The `Iterable` abstract class was removed from `collections` in Python 3.10, so it will result in an error trying to import it. If using `Iterable` from `collections.abc` doesn't work, you can try downgrading to Python 3.9 and try again.